# write fields of a vector class to an excel file

Tags: excel, vector

I am trying to write 4 fields of type double and 1 field of type string to an excel file.

`Vector<test_class.sigma_results> R = MainClass.calculateAllNames(R1, R2, Names);`

This is the method that calculates what I need for a specific stock name:

```
public sigma_results calculateSigmas(Vector<Double> r1, Vector<Double> r2, String name) {
        double[] W = {3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 25};
        sigma_results r = new sigma_results();
        r.sigma = sumSquared(r1,20);
        r.sigma_weighted_s2 = sumSquaredWeightedS2(r1, W, 20);
        r.sigma_weighted_s3 = sumSquaredWeightedS3(r1, W, 20);
        r.sigma_adj_weighted_s2 = sumSquaredWeightedS2(r2, W, 20);
        r.sigma_adj_weighted_s3 = sumSquaredWeightedS3(r2, W, 20);
        r.sigma_adj = sumSquared(r2,20);
        r.name = name;
        return r;
    }
```

And this is where I calculate the values for all stocks in my universe:

public Vector calculateAllNames(Vector R1, Vector R2, Vector Names) {

```
    Vector<sigma_results> R = new Vector<sigma_results>(1000);
    String current_name = "";

    Vector<Double> r1 = new Vector<Double>(20);
    Vector<Double> r2 = new Vector<Double>(20);

    for (int idx=0; idx<Names.size(); idx++) {
         if (Names.elementAt(idx).equals(current_name)) {
            r1.add(R1.elementAt(idx));
            r2.add(R2.elementAt(idx));
         } else {
            //calculation here
            if (r1.size()>0) {
                R.add(calculateSigmas(r1, r2, current_name));
            }
            r1.clear();
            r2.clear();
            current_name = Names.elementAt(idx);
            r1.add(R1.elementAt(idx));
            r2.add(R2.elementAt(idx));
        }   
    }
    return R;
}
```

So, I need to write each of these fields into a column in excel so that I can have my output corresponding to each individual stock name. What is the best way to write these individual fields to excel? I am unsure exactly how to access them in the first place, which is part of the problem. Still very new to Object Oriented Programming as I was working MATLAB for a while. Closest thing we had was a structure....

Comment: which source language is this? c#? best tag it as such in order to get the right people to look at it!

Answer (score 0):

Vector class makes me think this is Java. I'm not quite sure what field you wish to write to Excel (I'm guessing the name of the stock and some of the r.sigma... values.

What I would probably do is write a [Comma separated values file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). Something like this:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("c:\\export.csv", "UTF-8");
for(sigma_results s : R){
    string oneLine = s.name + "," + s.firstField + "," s.secondField + "," + s.thirdField + "," + s.fourthField;
    // write the line to the file
    writer.println(oneLine);
}
writer.close();
```